# How to support multiple languages in Swift?

Tags: ios, swift

I'm creating an app and need to support the language of the device and I haven't found any info online regarding that.

How to get to the device language support and present it in Swift?

Comment: What do you mean by "getting the device language support and present it in Swift"? Do you mean you want to check what language the device is currently set to and change your app's language to that language?

Comment: https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/i18n !?

Answer (score 0):

The question is a bit incomplete. what i understood from your question is that you want to know the device language.

if that is the case, this is how you get the current device language

```
    let langStr = Locale.current.languageCode
    print("Language: %@",langStr)
```